# Association in rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Below is the model Structure.

```
class UserFamilyRole < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user_family
   belongs_to :user_role
   belongs_to :organization
end

class UserFamily < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_family_roles
   has_many :user_roles
end
```

I am looking for below result from the above **UserFamilyRole** table.

```
  {
     user_family1: [user_role1, user_role2],
     user_family2: [user_role1, user_role2, user_role3]
     ...
  }
```

I achieved this Result from below query:

```
  user_family_roles = UserFamilyRole.where(:organization_id => org_id)
  results = {}
  juser_family_roles.each do |user_family_role|
    user_family = UserFamily.find(user_family_role.user_family_id)
    result[user_family.name] = user_family.user_roles.collect(&:title)
  end

 puts results
```

But Above query doesn't look optimized one so can anyone help me to write the **optimized** query. 
In our App **org_id** is present.

Comment: Your association names should be snake_case (as should the columns). `belongs_to :user_family` and `has_many :user_family_roles`. Using CamelCase will generate really unconventional method names in camelcase.